# Access 2010: Filter a Report with multiple values in field based on specific combo box criteria

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm still fairly new to Access, so I apologize if this is pretty basic stuff.  I have a database with a table that contains the information of different companies and their products.  The user can enter multiple products in the "Product" field based on a drop-down, check box list.  For example, I could have the name of a company in the "Company Name" field, and then it could have up to four products that it produces "Toys, Household Appliances, Furniture, Cleaning Supplies" in the "Products" field.

I have created a report to generate a list of the companies by product.  The user opens a form where they can select one of the products in a drop-down list and then hit go.  Ideally, the report generated contains all of the suppliers that produce that product.  However, my problem is that if a company produces multiple products, the filter doesn't include that company, since it doesn't match the specified criteria exactly.

Basically what I'm looking for some way to tell the report to filter for all companies if it CONTAINS a specific product, not just equals that product.  I'm not sure how to do this.  I hope that makes sense, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two tables (probably actually three; I'll go with three).

**Company table**
Company information: Name, address, phone no, etc, plus an ID field which will be integer, Auto (automatically assigned by Access) and will be the Primary Key.

**ProductType table**
A list if your product types (Toys and so on). Will contain an ID defined as per the ID in the Customer table.

**CustomerProduct table**
This will also have an ID as per the other two. It will also have two int fields: CustomerID and ProductTypeID. These will contain the value of the ID column in the Customer and ProductType tables. These will be defined as Foreign Keys: Access won't allow you to put e.g. 10 in ProductTypeID unless ProductType has a row with an ID of 10. This is known as Referential Integrity and helps ensure that your data is consistent.

You can also create a Unique index on CustomerID and ProductID (one index on two fields). This will ensure that you don't get the same ProductType/Customer combo in the database twice.

**Queries**
You can now use the rows in ProductType for your drop downs which contain Product Types. If you need to add one, you just add a row in the ProductType table and the code will pick it up.
To get your list of customers who carry a ProductType, you do a join between Customer and CustomerProduct. Something like:

```
select *
from Customer c
inner join CustomerProduct p on p.CustomerID = c.ID
where p.ProductTypeID = 10
```

(assuming that the product type they're looking for has an ID of 10).

This is actually the correct way to do it. Your way - having multiple ProductTypes on one customer row - makes things a bit tricky. There is a way around your immediate problem but I'm not going there as this type of design, while non an unusual beginners mistake, leads to horrific problems later on. Do it correctly from the start.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That worked great.  I figured it had to be some kind of design issue.  Thanks again!